# PostgreSQL, Sequelize return null if row does not exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I make a call to the database and there is no row what I need, the query returns null, can I make the query return all existing fields

```js
supplierRouter.get('/:supplier_id', async (req, res) => {
  let [supplier] = await Promise.all([
    models.supplier.model.findOne({
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'order',
        'type',
        'credit_card_id',
        'max_payment',
        'max_percentage_profit',
        'min_percentage_profit',
        'status',
        Sequelize.literal(`
              "SupplierContact"."name" AS "contact_name",
              "SupplierContact"."phone" AS "contact_phone_number",
              "SupplierColor"."logo_background" AS "logo_background_color",
              "SupplierColor"."light_logo_background_color" AS "light_logo_background",
              "Address"."street" AS "address",
              "Document"."url" AS "image", 
              "LL_Document"."url" AS "light_logo"
           `),
      ],
      include: [
        { model: models.supplierContact.model, as: 'SupplierContact' },
        { model: models.address.model, as: 'Address' },
        { model: models.supplierColor.model, as: 'SupplierColor' },
        {
          model: models.business.model,
          attributes: ['id'],
          through: {
            attributes: [['supplier_id', 'id']],
            where: { is_authorized: true },
          },
          as: 'Business',
          require: true,
        },
        {
          model: models.document.model,
          as: 'Document',
          where: { type: getTypeNum('image', 'Document') },
          through: {
            attributes: [['supplier_id', 'id']],
          },
          require: false,
        },
        {
          model: models.document.model,
          require: false,
          as: 'LL_Document',
          where: { type: getTypeNum('light_logo', 'Document') },
          through: {
            attributes: [['supplier_id', 'id']],
          },
        },
      ],
      raw: true,
      where: {
        id: req.params.supplier_id,
        '$Business.id$': { [Op.ne]: null },
      },
      includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
    }),
  ]).catch((e) => console.error(e));
  console.log(supplier);
  res.send(supplier);
});
```

In this case, I don't have "light_logo" field. And I need to get an object from DB without this field, if it does not exists. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. findOne returns null if no record matches the query. You want it to return all rows..? Also, why are you using Promise.all? You have only one promise.

Comment: It''s `required`. You need to pass `required: true` to join only if record exist in other table, or it will join and make included model `null`